# 2 LT spice model are the same but one is not generating correct results

Tags: ltspice

I cannot figure out the difference between these 2 ltspice schematics.  They appear to be identical in settings but one graphs the capacitor charging over time and the other starts the capacitor at full charge.  I see no difference between them, it is bizarre.

Does anyone see a difference?

I do not know how to attach a file, so here are links to both ltspice files.

This one called Capacitor is ok:
https://tresor.it/s#Mr8RP_dn7bhLpmZFFl1-LA

This one called CarBattery is fried
https://tresor.it/s#nJhxnQ5sKx3_m7SkEDVKoA

Comment: For your next time, please use the builtin image uploader, or, if you don't have enough points, upload to `imgur` and post the link.

Comment: they're not photos, they'e save files if you don't have ltspice (I've yet to hear a good excuse) you can see the netlist in any text viewer.

Answer (score 2):

It's the difference between one farad and one femto-farad

`1F` in spice is "one femto farad" ("1fF")  which is so low as to approximate an open circuit. a million billion times smaller what you expected.

You've got to be careful with spice.

Another common trap is that `M` is always "milli"  to get "mega" you need to write `meg`